# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with pandas for the first time and not sure if what I'm attempting is the best way to accomplish this, but I'm parsing an Excel sheet, trying to make a list of every number in a certain column (column 'C' in my case).

I returned everything from column 'C', removed the empty cells and now I'm trying to remove the '#' character that's in front of the numbers.

Here's my code from ***before*** I tried to remove the '#' character, so you can see the output:

```
def get_prod_cmvp_data():
    prod_cmvp_data = pd.read_excel('_Request ID__Client Cryptographic Module List Template.xlsx', usecols = 'C', header = 6, )
    prod_cmvp = prod_cmvp_data.dropna()
    vals = prod_cmvp.values
    print(vals)

output:

[['#3914']
 [' #3907']
 [' #3197']
 ['#4272']
 ['#4271']
 ['#4254']
 ['#3784']
 ['#3946']
 ['#3888']
 ['#4174']
 ['#4222']
 ['#3613']
 ['#3125']
 ['#3140']
 ['#3197']
 [' #3196']
 [' #3644']
 [' #3615']
 ['#3651']
 ['#3918']
 ['#3946']
 ['#4271']
 ['#3888']
 ['#4174']
 ['#4222']
 ['#3613']
 ['#3125']
 ['#3140']]
```

Here's my code ***after*** I tried to remove the '#' character

```
def get_prod_cmvp_data():
    prod_cmvp_data = pd.read_excel('_Request ID__Client Cryptographic Module List Template.xlsx', usecols = 'C', header = 6, )
    prod_cmvp = prod_cmvp_data.dropna()
    vals = prod_cmvp.values
    values = vals.str.replace("#", "")
    print(values)

Output:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Excel File:

Here's a link to the spreadsheet on google sheets, if that's any easier

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yBU4XrfMk54kQorOD7GCQ6kGBYzY_RGf10aHIKy4HLo/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.values` returns a ndarray so won't work with .str.replace.

You should be able to drop

```
vals = prod_cmvp.values
```

And use pandas string methods on the pandas series object instead:

```
prod_cmvp = prod_cmvp_data.dropna()["C"].str.replace("#", "")
```

Caveats: From what you posted it's not easy to reproduce your input data. The solution above assumes column C holds an array of strings when read with pd. read_excel. Also, it's assumed it's called "C" otherwise replace the string '["C"]' with your correct column name. If you need to see the column names:

```
prod_cmvp_data.columns
```

Comment: I added the excel file (hopefully I did that correctly) and made the suggested changes and got this error ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'```

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot - I think what would be useful is the actual excel file itself.  I've edited the answer to suggest the fix.

Comment: When I run "print(prod_cmvp_data.columns)" this is the output: ```Index(['Unnamed: 2'], dtype='object')``` when I tried the fix I got a ```Key Error: 'C'```

Comment: I'm not sure how to add spreadsheets, but I uploaded it to google docs and added the link

Comment: The key error means it can't find the column name as mentioned in the text above

Answer (score 0):

please provide excel file, it can done elegantly while reading from file. solution to current problem as below.

```
col=[['#3914'],
[' #3907'],
[' #3197'],
['#4272'],
['#4271'],
['#4254'],
['#3784'],
['#3946'],
['#3888'],
['#4174'],
['#4222'],
['#3613'],
['#3125'],
['#3140'],
['#3197'],
[' #3196'],
[' #3644'],
[' #3615'],
['#3651'],
['#3918'],
['#3946'],
['#4271'],
['#3888'],
['#4174'],
['#4222'],
['#3613'],
['#3125'],
['#3140']]

for i in col:
    i[0]=i[0].replace('#', '')
```

Comment: I just added the excel file, hopefully I did it correctly

Comment: @MitchellPrivett- i can only see snap shot of excel file. better to upload the excel file.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add spreadsheets, but I uploaded it to google docs and added the link for that